# Heroku & Django & Celeri & Redis: "State changed from up to crashed" without any explanation

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

I created a Django app that I deployed on Heroku. The app is processing an important background task (It takes 5-10mn to be run). It involves scraping data and creating a plotly visualisation. The background task is handled through a Celeri app. The communication between Celeri and Django is done with Redis.

Everything is working well locally. Everything is working well with a small amount of data scraped (dataframe with 50 rows). But as soon as I increase the amount of data used (dataframe > 50 rows), the Heroku worker crash without any error message.

```
2020-05-18T12:32:11.945988+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.101.144.240 - - [18/May/2020:12:32:11 +0000] "GET /task/bef2fea5-b7f7-4c37-b32e-2a7888486925/ HTTP/1.1" 200 77 "https://community-detection-instagram.herokuapp.com/parameters/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"
2020-05-18T12:32:14.039229+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-05-18T12:32:14.042067+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

It has always happened **during the creation of the plot**, which is the last step of my background task.

Again, the visualisation is working well when I scrape only a few amounts of data (even in production). I thought it could be a memory problem, but it looks that I'm not using all of it.

[screen of the memory usage from heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr0kj.png)

I'm keen to have your ideas. Can a background task be too heavy for Heroku / Redis? Why does the worker crash without any error message?

PS: I'm **not** storing the data scraped in a database. It's "only" a 500rows pandas data frame which is created during the scraping phase of the background task. Can it be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

After refreshing the memory dashboard, it looks like it's a memory issue.

[New screen of the Heroku memory report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU8Yy.png)

Just in case someone is facing the same issue, I had to upgrade my Heroku plans to see the memory report.